How can I add local subtitles to Media3?
I'm trying to implement srt subtitles into my videos but I don't understand how they work in the new media3. The files have the same exact name of the video file but .srt
public class VideoPlayerFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private PlayerView playerView;
    private ExoPlayer exoPlayer;
    private MediaFile mediaFile;
    
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(PrefUtils.PREF))
            PrefUtils.with(MainActivity.getInstance()).setSharedPref(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        ActivityUtils.with(requireContext()).enableFullscreen(requireActivity().getWindow());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video_player, container, false);
        playerView = view.findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
        progressLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.progressLayout);
        playerVideoTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.playerVideoTitle);
        playerBack = view.findViewById(R.id.playerBack);
        unlockLock = view.findViewById(R.id.unlockLock);
        rewind = view.findViewById(R.id.rewind);
        previous = view.findViewById(R.id.previous);
        pausePlay = view.findViewById(R.id.pausePlay);
        next = view.findViewById(R.id.next);
        forward = view.findViewById(R.id.forward);
        rotateDevice = view.findViewById(R.id.rotateDevice);
        pipMode = view.findViewById(R.id.pipMode);
        playVideo();
        subtitles.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            useSubtitles = !useSubtitles;
            videoData.saveVideoData(mediaFile.getPath(), exoPlayer.getContentPosition());
            resetPlayer();
            playVideo();
            subtitles.setImageResource(useSubtitles ? R.drawable.ic_subtitles_on : R.drawable.ic_subtitles_off);
        });
        return view;
    }

    @OptIn(markerClass = UnstableApi.class)
    private void playVideo() {
        if (mediaFile == null) {
            if (intentVideoUri == null) {
                mediaFile = videoPlayerViewModel.getMediaFileList().get(position);
            } else {
                mediaFile = new MediaFile().getMediaFromUri(requireContext(), intentVideoUri);
            }
        }
        databaseVideoData = videoData.getVideoData(mediaFile.getId());
        String path = mediaFile.getPath();
        playerVideoTitle.setText(mediaFile.getDisplayName());
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
        DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(requireContext());
        DefaultTrackSelector.Parameters trackSelectorParameters = trackSelector.buildUponParameters().clearOverridesOfType(C.TRACK_TYPE_TEXT).setPreferredTextLanguage(
                "en").build();
        trackSelector.setParameters(trackSelectorParameters);
        exoPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(requireContext()).setTrackSelector(trackSelector).setLoadControl(new DefaultLoadControl()).build();
        DefaultDataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSource.Factory(requireContext(), DataSchemeDataSource::new);
        exoPlayer.setTrackSelectionParameters(trackSelectorParameters);
        playerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);

        // Add subtitle configuration if subtitles are enabled
//        if (useSubtitles) {
        File file = new File(mediaFile.getPath());
        String name = file.getName();
        int pos = name.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (pos > 0) {
            name = name.substring(0, pos);
        }
        Uri subtitleUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(file.getParent() + "/" + name + ".srt"));
        MediaItem.SubtitleConfiguration subtitleConfiguration =
                new MediaItem.SubtitleConfiguration.Builder(subtitleUri)
                        .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP)
                        .setLanguage("en")
                        .setSelectionFlags(C.SELECTION_FLAG_DEFAULT)
                        .build();
        MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem.Builder().setUri(uri).setSubtitleConfigurations(ImmutableList.of(subtitleConfiguration)).build();
//        }
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(mediaItem);
        playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        exoPlayer.setMediaSource(mediaSource);
        exoPlayer.prepare();
        exoPlayer.seekTo(exoPlayer.getCurrentMediaItemIndex(), databaseVideoData == null ? C.TIME_UNSET : databaseVideoData.getVideoPosition() <= 0 ? C.TIME_UNSET : databaseVideoData.getVideoPosition());
        exoPlayer.play();
        exoPlayer.addListener(new Player.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaybackStateChanged(int playbackState) {
                if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_ENDED) {
                    exoPlayer.pause();
                    pausePlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                    exoPlayer.seekTo(exoPlayer.getCurrentMediaItemIndex(), 0);
                    videoData.saveVideoData(mediaFile.getId(), exoPlayer.getContentPosition());
                    if (PrefUtils.with(requireContext()).getBoolean("autoplayNext", false)) {
                        nextVideo();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        mediaSession = new MediaSession.Builder(requireContext(), exoPlayer).setCallback(new MediaSession.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(@NonNull MediaSession session, @NonNull MediaSession.ControllerInfo controllerInfo, @NonNull Intent intent) {
                KeyEvent keyEvent = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
                if (keyEvent != null && keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    int keyCode = keyEvent.getKeyCode();
                    switch (keyCode) {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE:
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY:
                            playPauseVideo();
                            return true;
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT:
                            nextVideo();
                            return true;
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS:
                            previousVideo();
                            return true;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }).build();
    }

    private PendingIntent getMainActivityPendingIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(requireContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(requireContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (!PrefUtils.with(MainActivity.getInstance()).getBoolean("backgroundPlay", false)) {
            exoPlayer.pause();
            pausePlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(PrefUtils.PREF))
            PrefUtils.with(MainActivity.getInstance()).setSharedPref(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        if (exoPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            pausePlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
        } else {
            if (!PrefUtils.with(MainActivity.getInstance()).getBoolean("backgroundPlay", false)) {
                pausePlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        resetPlayer();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void resetPlayer() {
        try {
            if (exoPlayer != null) {
//                MainActivity.getInstance().notificationManager.cancel(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID);
                exoPlayer.pause();
                videoData.saveVideoData(mediaFile.getId(), exoPlayer.getContentPosition());
                exoPlayer.stop();
                exoPlayer.release();
                mediaSession.release();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

and I use
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.fragments.VideoPlayerFragment">

    <androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_playback_view"
        app:hide_on_touch="true"
        app:resize_mode="fit"
        app:show_timeout="3000"
        app:shutter_background_color="@color/app_background"
        app:surface_type="surface_view" />
</FrameLayout>

Can someone help me? I have tried some things online but they all use exoplayer2.
If you want help me with code improvement I'm open to suggestions.
Also, app:show_timeout="3000" hides the timebar after 3s and controls after 6 (3s the timebar and 3s for the layout) how can I change it?
P.s. I know fragment is bad for video player, I'll change it soon

wheres the subtitle file stored on the device?

Same folder of the video so, for example, /storage/emulated/0/movies/video.srt (or mp4). Do i need storage permission for that? Because now I use media permission to have access to videos android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media

well you cannot do that because of the storage access restrictions. put the srt file in your apps private directory and access it at context.getFilesDir(); or request the user to open it with storage access framework

What about the time bar disappearing after 3s and everything else after 3s + 3s? I would like to make everything disappear with the defautltimebar after 3s

@kpwnApps Placing it in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data//files/ or /data/user/0//files did nothing. I can't see the subtitles anyway
